# how to view the content of /dev/sda file?

Tags: dd, cat, disk-formatting

I formatted a 160GB drive using:

```
dd if=/dev/zeros of=/dev/sda bs=512
```

I expect the entire drive is filled with zeros, but how do I check it?

I thought I could just `cat /dev/sda` and see all zeros, however, after I did that, the terminal appeared to freeze.

Comment: What's the point ? Disk drives are opposed to be partitioned (with gparted or other partitioning tool) and the partitions formatted into filesystems (in gparted, mkfs or similar)and the mounted. And you don't "format" a drive by overwriting it by zeroes, you just remove any information, including need partitioning and filesystems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Notice on usage

It is `/dev/zero` and not `/dev/zeros` so your command should be:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512
```

And not:

```
dd if=/dev/zeros of=/dev/sda bs=512
```

#### How to verify?

There are many ways to verify the drive contains only zeros but opening the drive as a file and viewing it is not the most efficient method at all.

A simple method wold be to use [`cmp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man1/cmp.1.html) which will compare two files byte by byte and report the first difference. Basically, you would compare `/dev/zero` as a file ( all zeros ) to your drive as another file like so:

```
cmp /dev/zero /dev/sda
```

If you get something like this:

```
cmp: EOF on....
```

Then files are identical up to the end of the shorter file ( your drive in this case ) and all there are are zeros.

A difference would be reported by `cmp` with something like this:

```
... differ: byte 1, line 1
```

Answer (score 4):

I am sure it didn't freeze; it just takes a looong time. One screenful (80x25) are 1920 characters, i.e. not quite 2k. And you are trying to view 160 GB worth of zeroes, i.e.

160 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 characters, i.e. 171798691840 characters.

I hope you didn't make any plans for the next few weeks... ;-)

Comment: what would be the best way to view a the large file a few block at a time?

Comment: You can try your luck with `od -x /dev/sda | less`

Comment: ...but the point is: This is a pointless undertaking. When you stare at those zeroes for hours, you will realize at some point that you _still_ haven't even seen the first percent of it all.

Comment: i was just asking out of pure curiosity. I was planning to write different patterns and was wondering what they would look like.